# Foreach not iterating properly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to iterate an outer array client_idArr which has multiple ids item_to and item_for has multiple integer values, item_from is less than item_to.The problem is the client_idArr is iterating only once.please help

My code:

```
 foreach ($client_idArr as $id) {

 for ($i=0; $i <= sizeof($item_from); $i++) { 

  for ($j=$item_from[$i]; $j <=$item_to[$i] ; $j++) { 

      $item_Arr = array(
                              'id'=>$id,
                              'item_for'=>$j,
                              'charge_per_item'=>$charge_per_item[$i] 
                             );
      $insertItem = $this->model->addCharges($item_Arr);
     }
   }

  }
```

Comment: what is the structure of $client_idArr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an array's indexes are between 0 and size-1 
so change your code like this :
 for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($item_from); $i++) {